# Jquery change selected value

Tags: html, jquery, css

Please help with simple example. How to make with jquery that by clicking on the button its value get into the .selected block ?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.row div {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selected">Selected text</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>select item 1</div>
  <div>select item 2</div>
  <div>select item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Post your jQuery Code.

Comment: Where is your button? Where is your JavaScript/jQuery? Where did you get stuck? What help do you need? What went wrong (and in what way)? Were there any errors, what were they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will trigger click event for any div inside the div having 'row' class. CurrentTarget will get the reference of the selected div. And .html() gets and sets the text of the selected div.

```
$(".row div").click(function(e) {
    $('.selected').html($(e.currentTarget).html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // do something with the text
});
```

The `.text()` method will return the text content for that `<div>`, (as well as any nested elements).

If you only wanted the click event on certain `<div>` elements, the best is to add a `class`, and select the correct ones based on that.